# didSet not getting called on every mutation?

Tags: arrays, swift, didset

I have a variable that I want to have a listener for when you set and mutate and didSet seems like the perfect candidate. However, in my initial testing of it, the first append triggers the did set and (in my example) the JS loads into my webview, however I never see the second append hit my breakpoint on the didSet and the JS does not run because it must not have loaded. What can be going on?

```
var additionalJSFilesToRun: [(String, WKUserScriptInjectionTime)] {
    didSet {
        for (string, time) in additionalJSFilesToRun {
            guard !self.jsFiles.contains(string) else { return }
            guard let jsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: string, ofType: "js"), let jsSource = try? String(contentsOfFile: jsPath) else { return }
            let script = WKUserScript(source: jsSource, injectionTime: time, forMainFrameOnly: false)
            self.webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
            jsFiles.insert(string)
        }
    }
}
```

In another class:

```
webView.additionalJSFilesToRun.append(("ABC", .atDocumentStart))
webView.additionalJSFilesToRun.append(("DEF", .atDocumentStart))
```

Only ABC is triggering the didSet. Any thoughts why one mutation is doing it but another isn't?

Comment: did you added print() to log? and count?

Comment: Did a print and indeed it was called the correct amount of times. The problem was the return in the guard statement. It should be a continue otherwise it will do the first one only every time. Dumb mistake. Now to close this...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the return in the guard should be a continue, otherwise since it is based off the oldValue as well, it would end execution after the first tuple.